# Softmax function of 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

Hello guys i have the follown matrix of shape [5,3] and i would like to get the softmax function.

```
array([[340.        ,  59.33333333, 348.11111111],
       [292.5       ,  46.5       , 297.875     ],
       [301.14285714,  48.28571429, 307.71428571],
       [307.        ,  50.        , 319.28571429],
       [307.77777778,  48.44444444, 313.44444444]])
```

The name of the above matrix is e_l1, i tried this code i get a matrix but when i am trying to sum each row the result is not 1 so that means that my outcome is wrong.

```
e= np.exp(e_l1- np.max(e_l1))
S= np.sum(e,axis=0)
P= e/S
```

As result i get this:

```
 [[1.00000000e+00 9.99874329e-01 1.00000000e+00]
 [2.34969834e-21 2.66992811e-06 1.52312011e-22]
 [1.33216272e-17 1.59230195e-05 2.85681188e-18]
 [4.65888615e-15 8.84158760e-05 3.02892988e-13]
 [1.01406710e-14 1.86621235e-05 8.79949929e-16]]
```

and as result of the summation of the rows this:

```
[2.99987433e+00 2.66992811e-06 1.59230195e-05 8.84158763e-05
```

1.86621235e-05]

Does anybody know what happen here ? I think the formula that i use is correct

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just used the wrong axis  for your sum, because you are computing the probabilities for each row, you need to divide each element in the row by the sum of all elements within this same row

```py
e = np.exp(e_l1- np.max(e_l1))
S = np.sum(e,axis=1)
P = e/np.expand_dims(S, 1)

print(P.sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: As i see in the internet the right is to compute the sum of the elements across columns, ins't it ?

Comment: Well It is up to you based on your use-case. But if you're dealing with a machine learning problem, then generally each row represents a sample of your data, and the columns the predicted logits by your model for each class. What you want is: for each sample compute the probability of it beloging to ne class. That's why yu normalize each row independantly for each row (thus the `sum(axis=1)`). That way you'll have the sum of each row == 1. If this is not your use-case then your question is not quite clear please edit it to include more information on your use case